# multiplying 2 square roots , where only one of them is negative

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

I have just started learning complex numbers. So I might be wrong here...
Can you do: $\sqrt{a} * \sqrt{b} = \sqrt{a*b}$
where 'a' is a negative number and 'b' is a positive number

Comment: What happens if you take the square of each side of your equation?

Comment: Unfortunately, in Complex Analysis, for non-zero complex $z = re^{i\theta},~~\sqrt{z}$ is ambiguous, since for $w_1 = \sqrt{r} e^{i(\theta/2)}~~$ and $~~w_2 = \sqrt{r} e^{i[\pi + (\theta/2)]}~~$ both $w_1$ and $w_2$ satisfy $w^2 = z.$

Comment: In general you *shouldn't* but in this case $\sqrt{a}\sqrt b = \sqrt{-|a|}\sqrt{|b|}=i\cdot \sqrt{|a|}\sqrt{|b|}=i\sqrt{|ab|}$.  And $\sqrt{ab}= \sqrt{-|a||b|}=\sqrt{-|ab|}=i\sqrt{|ab|} = \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ so it's okay.  But in general WATCH OUT FOR MULTIPLE ROOTS!!!!  They *WILL* bite you on the butt!

Comment: "What happens if you take the square of each side of your equation? "  That won't prove they are equal.  That will only prove they have the both have the same square.

Comment: @fleablood exhibit A: $(-2)^2=2^2$ but $-2 \neq 2$

Comment: @Nyra.  That was my point.  $(\sqrt{a}*\sqrt b)^2 = ab$ and $\sqrt{ab} = ab$.  But that doesn't mean $\sqrt{a}*\sqrt b=\sqrt ab$.

Answer (score 0):

First, in complex numbers, there is no "positive" and "negative" numbers. Those notions exist only in real numbers. If $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, and $a$ is negative, it is not correct to write "square root of $a$" even though it is clear what you mean : a complex number $z$ such that its square equals $a$. With this notation, this is correct: let $z$ be complex number whose square is $a$, $w$ complex number whose square is $b$, then the square of $zw$ is $ab$ just by commutativity of multiplication.

Comment: Unfortunately, in Complex Analysis, you can't say that $\sqrt{z} \times \sqrt{w} = \sqrt{zw}$, because $\sqrt{z}$ is an ambiguous expression.  See my comment following the question.

Comment: " If a and b are real numbers, and a is negative, it is not correct to write "square root of a" even though it is clear what you mean" ..... You are saying it is not correct to write $\sqrt{-4} = 2i$?

Comment: it is not correct. Both $2i$ and $-2i$ have square $-4$. That is what this user is writing as well. @user2661923 I said I understood his question, and explained what and how, yes I know "you can't write it", but to this man it is not clear. And when you do write it in satisfactory manner, it is correct